# Change of direction of a vector

Tags: math, geometry, 3d

Given two vectors in three dimensions pointing different directions. I would like the first vector be able to change direction a set number of degrees towards the second vector. What is the formula or algorithm to calculate this new vector.

For example a space-ship (this is for a space-ship simulator) is pointing in the direciton of (2,3,3). The ship will now change direction 20 degrees in the direction to the vector of (2,-3,-2). What would the new vector be. It is not rotating along an axis, but rather at a right angle to both vectors.

Comment: Where is the space ship? You need a point of origin to calculate the rotation from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you want to rotate A toward B.

Take the cross product AxB = C and normalize it.

<strike>Now break A into two components, one parallel to C and one normal:</strike>

```
...
```

<strike>Now construct a vector normal to A and C (with the right sense):</strike>

```
...
```

<strike>Now you can construct the rotated vector:</strike>

```
...
```

**EDIT**
I feel like an idiot. The correct (and more simple) derivation is

```
F = C x A

G = cos(theta) A + sin(theta) F
```

**EDIT:**
This works by simple geometry. C is normal to the plane containing A and B. F is in the plane, and normal to A. So any vector in the plane is a linear combination of A and F; that is, any vector Z in the plane can be constructed as Z = aA + bF, where a and b are numbers, and any such sum will be in the plane. F also has the same magnitude as A, so if we construct

```
G = cos(theta) A + sin(theta) F
```

what we get is a vector with the same magnitude, but separated from A by an angle theta. (This is not immediately obvious, but if you play around with it a little you'll see that it works.)

Using your example:

```
A = (2, 3, 3) (magnitude = 4.69)
B = (2, -3, -2)
C = AxB = (3, 10, -12) (magnitude = 15.906)

Now normalize:
C = (0.189, 0.629, -0.754) (magnitude = 1.0)

F = CxA = (4.149, -2.075, -0.692) (magnitude = 4.69)

theta = 20 degrees
G = cos(theta) A + sin(theta) F = (3.299, 2.109, 2.583) (magnitude = 4.69)
```

G is in the same plane as A and B (normal to C), and the angle between A and G is 20 degrees. (The angle between A and B is 124.7 degrees, the angle between G and B is 104.7 degrees.)

Comment: A . (AxB) = 0, so D is 0. Why is it calculated at all?

Comment: Also, that results in E = A, F = C x A, which makes F parallel to B. So in effect you're just weighing the vectors A and B using cos(theta) and k*sin(theta). Does not work.

Comment: @Ollie Etuaho: thank you, I was wrong, I have corrected my answer. (Your first comment was correct, your second incorrect.)

Comment: Oh, I realized my error. Still, I wonder what this approach is based on? I can't immediately see how it works, could you elaborate on it a bit?

Comment: Before I try and figure this out (it has been 15 years since I last had to deal with vectors in school).

A is first vector, B is second vector, C = AxB, F = CxA, theta is the amount I am rotating and G is the final direction = cos(theta)A+sin(theta)F. Is this correct? Or am I missing something here.

Comment: @user631589: that's correct, except that you must normalize C (that is, make its magnitude 1) before you use it. I've tested this and it works-- I'll try to explain, as Olli Etuaho suggests.

Answer (score 3):

Take the cross product of two vectors to get the vector perpendicular to them.

Then you can rotate around that vector.

Comment: So how do I then do the rotation around that axis?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a rotation matrix. You can do it with pure trig if you want by defining a 3d circle and traveling along the rim of it, but I'd look into how to push and pop matrices from a stack - if you learn it now, it will make the rest of your game development tasks much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You must first compute the rotation vector, say:

```
Vector3 axis = crossProduct(Vector3(2,3,3), Vector3(2,-3,-2));
```

Then you make your rotation along that axis, using a rotation matrix.